# Fixed Footer Overflow Scroll

Tags: html, css, footer

I'm trying to create a fixed footer for my website but for some reason the overflow isn't working nor is the content scrolling. Here is my code:

```
<div id='footbar' style="bottom: 0;left: 0;width: 100%;min-width: 800px;position: fixed;background-color: red;border-top: 1px solid black">
Context
</div>
```

Comment: @yentup it's not up yet. It's just a website to display different information about photography and a few blogs. The footer is going to be used as a navigation bar.

Comment: As you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yentup/dGKL7/) it appears to be working fine.
There must be a problem with the rest of your page, can you post the code to that?

Comment: I'll be more specific. The footer is being placed where it needs to be but when the browser's size is "shrunk" there is no scroll bars to display the rest of the items in the footer, it's like the overflow is set to hidden when it's on scroll. @yentup I'm using a blank HTML page to test this, there's no content but this.

Comment: can you put it all into a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to mess around with?

Comment: @yentup notice how it's off the page? 
http://jsfiddle.net/XkFDL/

Comment: Bro, does [this](http://jsfiddle.net/yentup/XkFDL/1/) not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with pure css ..

When you use fixed positioning you are fixing the elements to the browsers viewport.

You will need javascript or jQuery ..